# Run debug configuration programmatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome DevTools to debug java script code and I need it to run programmatically from my plugin.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, for example to make a launch configuration?

Answer (score 2):

(If I understood the slightly brief question.)

You want to make a [`ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy.html), set the attributes on it, optionally save it, then [launch](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration.html#launch-java.lang.String-org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor-) it.

The [Launch Manager](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchManager.html) is very useful as you can do stuff with launches using it.

Here is a simple example:

```java
ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
ILaunchConfigurationType launchType = launchMgr.getLaunchConfigurationType("type id (from plugin.xml)");
ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy wc = launchType.newInstance(null, manager.generateLaunchConfigurationName("Name Here"));
wc.setAttributes(launchAttributes);
ILaunchConfiguration lc = wc.doSave();
Launch launch = lc.launch(ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE, new NullProgressMonitor());
```